# Test class for invocable method

Tags: apex, unit-test, invocable-method

I have no idea how to write a test class for an invocable class that I am using to reject all the adjustment records whose status field is updated as Rejected using Process Builder. I have created User, Account and Adjustments Records but I'm not getting the idea on how to cover the method.

```
/*
*
* AdjustmentAutoReject is used to Reject an Adjustment Approval Request once the Adjustment Status field is change as Rejected by Process Builder
*
*/
public with sharing class AdjustmentAutoReject {

    private List<ProcessInstance> process {get; set;}
    private List<ProcessInstanceHistory> stepOrWorkItem {get; set;}

    @InvocableMethod
    public static void RejectAdjustmentRecord(List<Id> adjIds){

    List<ProcessInstance> process = [SELECT Id, TargetObjectId, isDeleted, Status,
                                            (
                                                SELECT Id, ProcessInstanceId, ActorId, Actor.Name, StepStatus, Comments, ElapsedTimeInDays
                                                From StepsAndWorkItems
                                                Where 
                                                    StepStatus = 'Pending'  And
                                                    isDeleted = false 
                                                Order By 
                                                    Createddate Desc
                                                Limit 1
                                            )
                                        From ProcessInstance
                                        Where
                                            isDeleted = false and
                                            TargetObjectId In: adjIds and
                                            Status = 'Pending'
                                        Order By 
                                            Createddate Desc

                                ];
        if(process != null ) {
            for(ProcessInstance objProcessIns : process) {
                if(!objProcessIns.StepsAndWorkItems.isEmpty()) {
                    doStepsRejection(objProcessIns.StepsAndWorkItems[0].Id);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Auto Step level Rejection
    @TestVisible 
    private static void doStepsRejection(Id processStepId) {

        Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest req;
        Approval.ProcessResult result;  

        req = new Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest();
        req.setWorkitemId(processStepId);               
        req.setComments('Rejecting request.');
        req.setAction('Reject');
        result = Approval.process(req);

    }             

}

/*
*Test Class
*
*/

@isTest
public class AdjustmentAutoRejectTest {
  private static final String MANAGER_USER_ALIAS = 'TMU';
    private static final String STANDARD_USER_ALIAS = 'TSU';
    private static final String ENSEMBLE_ID = '12345678';
    private static final String CUID = 'AB1234';
    private static final String ADJUSTMENT_CREATED = 'Pending';
    private static final String ADJUSTMENT_APPROVED = 'Approved';
    private static final String ADJUSTMENT_REJECTED = 'Rejected';
    private static final String SYNC_STATUS_PENDING = 'Pending';
    private static final String SYNC_STATUS_ERROR = 'Error';
    private static final String BILLING_SOURCE_ENSEMBLE = 'Ensemble';
    private static final String ADJUSTMENT_MEMO = 'memo';
    private static final String ADJUSTMENT_CHARGE_ID = '942_1';
    private static final Decimal ADJUSTMENT_ORIGINAL_AMOUNT = 100;
    private static final Decimal ADJUSTMENT_AMOUNT = 10.00;
    private static final String ADJUSTMENT_REASON = 'AJ0402';
    private static final String BILL_SEQUENCE_NUMBER = 'AJ0402';
    private static final String ADJUSTMENT_CHARGE_SEQUENCE = '942';
    private static final Integer LIMIT_QUERIES_PLUS_ONE = Limits.getLimitQueries()+1;
    private static final Id RECORD_TYPE_ADJUSTMENT = RecordTypeCache.get(Schema.Dispute_Adjustment__c.SObjectType,'Adjustment').Id;


    @TestSetup static void setup() {
        User managerUser = (User)new SObjectBuilder(User.SObjectType)
                .put(User.Alias, MANAGER_USER_ALIAS)
                .create()
                .getRecord();
        User standardUser = (User)new SObjectBuilder(User.SObjectType)
                .put(User.Alias, STANDARD_USER_ALIAS)
                .put(User.ProfileId, SObjectFieldProviders.adminProfileProvider)
                .put(User.DelegatedApproverId, managerUser.Id)
                .put(User.Ensemble_Id__c, ENSEMBLE_ID)
                .put(User.CUID__c, CUID)
                .create()
                .getRecord();

        List<Account> accs = new SObjectBuilder(Account.sObjectType)
           .put(Account.OwnerId, standardUser.Id) 
           .put(Account.Name, new SObjectFieldProviders.UniqueStringProvider())
           .put(Account.AccountNumber, new SObjectFieldProviders.UniqueStringProvider()) 
           .put(Account.Billing_Source__c, BILLING_SOURCE_ENSEMBLE)
           .count(LIMIT_QUERIES_PLUS_ONE).create().getRecords();        

        //Create adjustments
        List<Dispute_Adjustment__c> adjustments = new SObjectBuilder(Dispute_Adjustment__c.SObjectType)
            .put(Dispute_Adjustment__c.Account__c, accs)
            .put(Dispute_Adjustment__c.Memo__c, ADJUSTMENT_MEMO)
            .put(Dispute_Adjustment__c.Manager_of_Pending_Approval_By__c, standardUser)
            .put(Dispute_Adjustment__c.RecordTypeId, RECORD_TYPE_ADJUSTMENT)
            .count(accs.size()).create().getRecords();
        new SObjectBuilder(Charge__c.SObjectType)
            .put(Charge__c.Dispute_Adjustment__c, adjustments)
            .put(Charge__c.Original_Amount__c, ADJUSTMENT_ORIGINAL_AMOUNT)
            .put(Charge__c.Amount__c, ADJUSTMENT_AMOUNT)
            .put(Charge__c.Adjustment_Reason__c, ADJUSTMENT_REASON)
            .put(Charge__c.Charge_Product_ID__c, ADJUSTMENT_CHARGE_ID)
            .put(Charge__c.Adjustment_Charge_Id__c, ADJUSTMENT_CHARGE_ID)
            .put(Charge__c.Bill_Sequence_Number__c, BILL_SEQUENCE_NUMBER)
            .put(Charge__c.Charge_Sequence_Number__c, ADJUSTMENT_CHARGE_SEQUENCE)
            .count(adjustments.size()).create().getRecords();


           }

     @isTest
     private static void givenRejectedAdjustments_whenStatusUpdate_byProcessBuilder(){

        User u = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Alias = :STANDARD_USER_ALIAS];
        List<Dispute_Adjustment__c> dispAdjs = [Select Id, RecordTypeId, Status__c FROM Dispute_Adjustment__c WHERE Status__C = :ADJUSTMENT_REJECTED];
        for(Dispute_Adjustment__c adj : dispAdjs){
            adj.Status__c = ADJUSTMENT_REJECTED;
        }

        Test.startTest();
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, mockResponse);
        System.runAs(u){
           // The following code runs as user 'u' 

        }
        Test.stopTest();

    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't even know how to begin, Trailhead is a more appropriate learning avenue. This site expects a good faith effort to solve the problem already be carried out.

Comment: Once you start writing a test class, you can **[edit]** this post to be more specific and it may get reopened.

Answer (score 0):

Your invocable method is just a static method. You can simply call it on your test to verify that it works as intended.

```
// create your test data here
// and get the ids to a "recordIds" list

Test.startTest();
AdjustmentAutoReject.rejectAdjustmentRecord(recordIds);
Test.stopTest();

// do your asserts here
```

Note: the fact that your method is called from the process builder means that it is going to run on **system mode**, so you don't really need the `runAs` method, and can modify the class to `without sharing` if you are not planning on using it outside process builder. If you do plan on using it outside process builder you can create a method run by a class without sharing that runs your original method.

Comment: Thanks for you prompt response.... could you please let me know what should be the input parameter ...

Comment: If your method signature says it accepts a list of ids, then you pass a list of ids to it.